# Android Studio error: UTF-16 (LE) byte order mark detected, but encoding is not supported

Tags: android, c++, encoding, utf-16, build-error

Im new to Android studio, and i wanted to make an app that uses my c++ code. Im importing the .cpp files using Cmake, and uppon building the project i get the following error:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\Android with arguments {SKD_Components\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe -C A:\...\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a native-lib}
ninja: Entering directory `A:\...\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a'
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/A_/Visual_Studio_Projects/.../filename.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/A_/Visual_Studio_Projects/.../filename.cpp.o 
"F:\Android SKD_Components\ndk\20.0.5594570\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe" --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain="F:/Android SKD_Components/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64" --sysroot="F:/Android SKD_Components/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot"  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -IA:/Visual_Studio_Projects/PasswordGenerator/PasswordGenerator -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/A_/Visual_Studio_Projects/.../filename.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\native-lib.dir\A_\Visual_Studio_Projects\...\filename.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/A_/Visual_Studio_Projects/.../filename.cpp.o -c A:/Visual_Studio_Projects/PasswordGenerator/PasswordGenerator.cpp
fatal error: UTF-16 (LE) byte order mark detected in 'A:/Visual_Studio_Projects/.../filename.cpp', but encoding is not supported
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Something to do with encoding, but i cant really figure out what.
Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that your
`filename.cpp` source file begins with a [UTF-16LE BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (bytes `FF FE`), indicating the content of the file has been encoded in UTF-16. The compiler you are using does not support compiling source files which are in that encoding. You need to change the encoding of your `.cpp` file to another encoding, preferably a 7/8-bit encoding such as UTF-8 or more likely just ASCII. Whichever editor you used to create that file, check if it has an option to specify a different encoding when saving files. Otherwise, you will have to use a 3rd party tool to re-encode the existing file, such as [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.15/iconv.1.html).